# Relationship between FISMA and OMB Circular A-130?

Tags: corporate-policy

Can someone explain to me the relationship between FISMA and OMB Circular A-130?

Comment: This a homework question?

Comment: Nope.  Hoping that a few people in the community here are familiar with federal information security policies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OMB Circulars are instructions or information issued by the Office of Management and Budget (OMB) to federal agencies. A-130 establishes official OMB policy and guidance on information technology management for federal executive agencies.

The Federal Information Security Management Act recognized the importance of information security to the economic and national security interests of the United States. The act requires each federal agency to develop, document, and implement an agency-wide program to provide information security for the information and information systems that support the operations and assets of the agency, including those provided or managed by another agency, contractor, or other source.

Have a look on [fismapedia](http://www.fismapedia.org/index.php?title=Doc%3aOMB_Circular_A-130) for more info on OMB A-130.

If you look at purpose it states:

> This Circular establishes policy for the management of Federal
>   information resources. OMB includes procedural and analytic guidelines
>   for implementing specific aspects of these policies as appendices.

FISMA requires agency program officials, chief information officers, and inspectors general (IGs) to conduct annual reviews of the agency’s information security program and report the results to Office of Management and Budget (OMB). OMB uses this data to assist in its oversight responsibilities and to prepare this annual report to Congress on agency compliance with the act.

**EDIT**

To put it a bit more simple as GdD phrased it:

> FISMA is a law that says federal government agencies have to protect
>   information resources. OMB A-130 says how they should go about it.

Comment: Basically, FISMA is a law that says federal government agencies have to protect information resources. OMB A-130 says how they should go about it.